# How to create header files and file handling

Tags: c, file, header

i start by saying that i´m really new to programing in c.

ok.... the question is not the same... i have fixed many things that look quite good despite the program just opens the files and does nothing more. i have got a bunch warnings but no errors.  the worning is allmoust allways the same... incopatible pointer type... can you please look to my code and help me? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                                                             //
//              Definitions - Informations to the preprocessor                                                 //
//                                                                                                             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define MAX_SIZE 1024
#define ERROROF "Could not open the file!!!"
#define SUCCESS "file sucessefuly opened!!!"


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                                                             //
//              Functions - Implementation of several functions                                                //
//                                                                                                             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int counting_lines(int *ptr){
char c;
int lines=0;

    do
    {
        c=fgetc(ptr);


        if (c="\n"){
            lines++;
        }
    }
    while((c!=EOF));

    return lines;
}


int freading_diff(int *ptr, int a, int numb_lines_total)    /* Function definition */
{
    char *lines2ptr;
    char lines2[numb_lines_total-2*a];

    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<numb_lines_total-2*a; i++){
    lines2[i]=fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, ptr);
}
    return &lines2ptr;

}



int freading_common(int *ptr1, int *ptr2, int a)    /* Function definition */
{
    char *lines1ptr;
    char lines1[2*a];
    lines1ptr=lines1[0];
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];

    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<a; i=i+2){
    lines1[i]=fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, ptr1);
    lines1[i+1]=fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, ptr2);
    }
return lines1ptr;

}


void screen_printing(char *lines1ptr, char *lines2ptr, int a, int numb_lines_total)
{
  int i=0;

  for (i=0; i<2*a; i++)
  {
      printf(lines1ptr+i);
  }
  for (i=0; i<numb_lines_total-2*a; i++)
  {
      printf(lines2ptr+i);
  }
}


void main(void)

{

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                                                             //
//                                             Opening the files                                               //
//                                                                                                             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    FILE *ptr1;
    FILE *ptr2;
    char filename1[255];           //variable to store the name of the first file
    char filename2[255];
    printf("First file : ");        //prompts the user about the name of the first file
    scanf("%63s", filename1);
    printf("Second file : ");        //prompts the user about the name of the first file
    scanf("%63s", filename2);

    if( (ptr1 = fopen(filename1,"r")) == NULL )    //checks if the first file can be opened
    {
        printf("%s %s \n",ERROROF, filename1);
        return -1;
    } else printf("%s %s ADDRESS %d\n",SUCCESS, filename1, &ptr1);
    if( (ptr2 = fopen(filename2,"r")) == NULL )    //checks if the first file can be opened
    {
        printf("%s %s \n",ERROROF, filename2);
        return -1;
    }else printf("%s %s ADDRESS %d\n",SUCCESS, filename2, &ptr2);


    int numb_lines_total=0;

    int a=0, b=0;

    int lines1=0, lines2=0;

    int *pointerline1, *pointerline2;

    int readlines1, readlines2;
    pointerline1=&readlines1;

    pointerline2=&readlines2;
    lines1=counting_lines(ptr1);
    lines2=counting_lines(ptr2);
    numb_lines_total = lines1+lines2;
    printf("First file has %d lines. Second file has %d lines. %d lines will be printed on the screen\n",lines1, lines2, numb_lines_total);

    if (lines1<lines2)
        {
        a= lines1;
        b= 2*a+1;
        readlines1=freading_diff(ptr2, a,  numb_lines_total);
        } else if (lines1>lines2)
                {
                    a= lines2;
                    b= 2 * a + 1;
                    readlines1=freading_diff(ptr1, a,  numb_lines_total);
                } else {
                       a= lines1;
                       }
    readlines2=freading_common(ptr1, ptr2, a);
    screen_printing(pointerline1, pointerline2,  a,  numb_lines_total);


    fclose(ptr1);
    fclose(ptr2);


    return;
}
```

Comment: `char x` is only a single char, not the whole file name. If you check `fopen` it takes a `const char* filename` parameter. Perhaps your function should do that too.

Answer (score 0):

your fopening function is openning a file but is not doing anything with it. The fp variable is a local variable that will disappear as soon as the program finish executing the function.

The "fopen" function returns a pointer to the beginning of the file, if you want to read the file, you'll need that pointer.

Besides that, I don't really know what do you want, you should specify it better.

What is the problem? does the code compile? does it print 1 or 0? I have no idea how to help

You really should've created another topic/edited your post instead of adding another answer asking more things.
Do you suppose anyone knows what does this "-1073741819 (0xC0000005)**" mean?
How do you know its memory violation? did it print an error saying that? did you run valgrind? I don't know any of that, you should really learn how to post here.

Aside from that, I think that your code is trying to print EOF.

```
file.txt
a
b  
c
EOF

1º loop - is scanf != EOF? yes, loop again
   print "a"
2º loop - is scanf != EOF? yes, loop again
   print "b"
3º loop - is scanf != EOF? yes, loop again
   print "c"
4º loop - is scanf != EOF? no. Do not loop again
   print "???"
```

Error.

Comment: what i really wanted was (for now) just open the file (i realised that i forgot to close the file). and print 0 or 1 just to see if the file was opened.

Comment: I think the only problem with your code is that you have declared a char as a parameter for fopening and you're passing a string to it. I've done my version of your code and it works